# Implementing MWC algorithm for Random generator

Tags: c#, random

One of my professors in university told us to write a random generator. 
He said that this is the function : `x[i] = (a*x[i-1] + c) Mod m`
and if your system is 64 bits number m is `(2^63) - 1`.

He wrote this pseudo code: (MWC algorithm)

```
a = 65539; x[0] = 65539; m = (2^63) -1;
x[i] = ax[i-1];
if x[i] < 0
    then  x[i] = x[i] + m;
    else R[i]  = x[i] /m;
end if
```

And I tried to implement it in c#. Here is code I have written :

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace Random_Generator
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {           
               float a = 65539;
               float[] x = new float[100];
               x[0] = 65539;
               float m = (float)  Math.Pow(2,63) - 1;
               for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
               {
                    x[i] = (a ) * x[i - 1];

                    if (x[i] < 0)
                        x[i] = x[i ] +  m;

                    Console.WriteLine("Random Number {0} is {1}", i, (float)(x[i]/m));
               }
         }
      }
 }
```

As He said it should generate `m` random unique numbers. But when I run this code only the first 62 numbers generate correctly. After that all of the numbers that are generated are `infinite`.

I really can't find the problem and I really need it.

Can any one please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need use `float` as you base type, you need use `long` that in c# means 64-bit signed integer.

Try this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
    long a = 65539;
    long[] x = new long[100];
    x[0] = 65539;
    long m = long.MaxValue; // equals to 2^63-1
    for(int i = 1; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        x[i] = a * x[i - 1];

        if (x[i] < 0)
            x[i] = x[i] + m;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Random Number {0} is {1}", i, x[i]/(float)m);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is real MWC algorithm, however it generates 100 different float numbers.